# Can I add Firestore rules for each collection I have?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So, for now im just trying to apply different rules to each one of the collections I have on my database but everytime i've tried this, it just rejects every operation no matter what, but accepts the operations if the rule is general for the whole database

```
    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
        match /databases/{database}/documents{
            match /users/{user} {
                allow read, write, update, delete: if 
                    request.auth !=null
            }
            match /productos/{product} {
                allow read;
                allow write, update, delete:
                    if request.auth !=null
                }
        
            match /business/{business} {
                allow read;
                allow write, update, delete: if 
                    request.auth !=null
            }
            match /orders/{order} {
                allow write, update, delete: if 
                    request.auth !=null
                allow read;
            }
        }
    }

    match /business/{business} {
        allow read;
        allow write, update, delete: if 
            request.auth !=null
    }
    match /orders/{order} {
        allow write, update, delete: if 
            request.auth !=null
        allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

this is what I'm trying and what I've seen on the internet but it just doesn't work

Comment: Partial explanation below.  Aside from that it is hard to say what isn't working, as rules on themselves don't do anything yet. Can you edit the question to include the minimal code that is needed to reproduce the unexpected rejection, including proof that the conditions in your rules are met (e.g. logging the current user just before accessing the database).

Comment: I solved the problem already, I didn't know i had to put the full path to the collections on every match statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matches are hierarchical, so they all need to be under `match /databases/{database}/documents{` to match anything in your database. So the last two `match` statements in your rules won't work unless you prefix the path with `/databases/{database}/documents`.

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much! this worked perfectly

Comment: I tried to, but my account is very new and i still don't have the reputation needed :(